# Vmlinuz not found when starting Laptop after installing Nitrux OS

Tags: system-installation, boot-loader

I am installing Ubuntu based Nitrux OS ( https://nxos.org )
I tried AutoInstall as well as manual partitioning. 
But after successfully Installing when I am restarting my Laptop it's saying ...

> Error Loading \vmlinuz: not found 
>   Failed to execute NXOS,using Linux
>   4.13.0(\vmlinuz) : not found

But Live USB boot is working fine.

I am using SAMSUNG RV509 Laptop.

Processor : i3
RAM : 3GB
Vcard : 1GB
Storage : 300GB

Btw I was using Windows7 befor Installing Nitrux OS.

Comment: can you show `/etc/fstab` from your installation? And as root or with sudo `bikld` and  `parted -l` also `dmidecode -t0` from your Live-Session? Edit your question for that.

Comment: Hi, I'm part of the team behind Nitrux. This error was due to missing modules in the Calamares installer, we have since updated our calamares packages and the ISO. See: https://github.com/nomad-desktop/calamares-settings-nxos/commit/648e937de184653d7a4e10077b239a5e6abeb202

Comment: @UriHerrera Yes Installed successfully but after Installing,Internet not working sir.Wifi and Wired both connecting but Chromium saying DNS server not found and ping,software center nothing working. ;_;

Comment: @Bahamut Thanks sir.Problem solved with new iso.